# Read file without fopen() (C language)

Tags: c, file, stdin, fopen

I am working on a school project in which we have to do some operations (select, min, max) on a table saved in .txt file.
The problem is that we can't use common functions such as fopen, fscanf, fclose.

The program will be launched from command line like this: `.\project.exe select parameters <table.txt`

Do you have some ideas how to get content of the .txt file to stdin without using fopen?
Thanks.

Comment: Ain't it should be `./project select parameters <table.txt`???

Comment: The command shell (DOS's cmd.exe in this case, probably) connects the std input of the program to the file when you call `prog < file`; it's equivalent to `cat file|prog` in unix. That is, a normal `scanf("%...)` will now read from the file, without the prog knowing it.

Comment: @shekharsuman The question you are trying to ask is "Shouldn't that be ...".   The answer is "not if it is Windows".

Comment: @GreenAsJade-OOPS,,,SORRY, I forgot about Windows!

Comment: @JamesMcLeod Since, unfortunately, OP apparently lives in Microsoft land, there are no `open`, `read` and `close` but [equivalent alternatives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y23kc048.aspx).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need to open the file - the operating environment will do it for you.

When your program is called with `<table.txt`, your standard input is switched to read from that file instead of the keyboard. You can use `scanf` to read the data, and do not worry about opening and closing the file.

Same goes for the output of your program and the `>table_out.txt` redirection: rather than printing to the screen, `printf`s in your program would be writing to a file, which would be automatically closed upon your program's exit. Of course if you need to print something to the screen when your output is redirected, you can do so by printing to `stderr` (e.g. `fprintf(stderr, "Invalid table format\n")`.

Comment: Thanks. I was launching the program in CodeBlocks and it didn't work as it should. Tried it in command line and works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to acomplish this.

## Reading STDIN

I guess the teacher wants this method in particular. The idea is reading standard input rather than particular file.
In C++ you can simply read the stdin object. Here's an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  char str[80];
  int i;

  printf("Enter a string: ");
  fgets(str, 10, stdin);

  /* remove newline, if present */
  i = strlen(str)-1;
  if( str[ i ] == '\n')
      str[i] = '\0';

  printf("This is your string: %s", str);

  return 0;
}
```

Source: http://www.java2s.com/Code/C/Console/Usefgetstoreadstringfromstandardinput.htm

## Using system utils

You can call "type" util @ Windows (not sure about it) or "cat" util in Linux as a subprocess to read some partticular file. But this is rather a "hack", so I do not recommend using this one.

Comment: the file is redirected to standard input so he doesnot need to open at all as its already opened